# Can I use more than 2 fields on a MongoDB aggregation framework $sort?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework

Using the following PyMongo Query. I used some tips from a Mongo Webinar, where they advised to use _id field to store a timestamp in order to improve performance and memory usage.

```
cursor = db.dados_meteo_reloaded.aggregate( [
{
    "$match": {
        "_id": {
        "$gte": "0001:20120901",
        "$lte": "0001:20140215"
    },
        "TMP": {
            "$lt": 7.2
    }
    }
    },
    {
"$project": {
    "year": {
        "$substr": [
            "$_id",
            5,
            4
        ]
    },
    "month": {
        "$substr": [
            "$_id",
            9,
            2
        ]
    },

            "day": {
        "$substr": [
            "$_id",
           11,
            2
        ]
    }
}
},
  {
 "$group": {
    "_id": {"year":"$year","month":"$month","day":"$day"},
    "frio": {
        "$sum": 0.25
    }
}
},
    {"$sort":{"_id.year":1, "_id.month":1, "_id.day":1}}
])
```

I get result that is only sorted by day. When , in the $sort step of the pipeline, I use only

```
{"$sort":{"_id.year":1, "_id.month":1}
```

The result came sorted by year and month correctly. Is there some limit on how many fields could be used on $sort step?

Here are some example documents

```
{
"_id" : "0001:20121201000000",
"RNF" : 0,
"WET" : 8,
"HMD" : 100,
"TMP" : 4.4
},
{
"_id" : "0001:20121201001500",
"RNF" : 0,
"WET" : 7.9,
"HMD" : 100,
"TMP" : 4.2
}
```

Comment: No, no limit that I know of. Can you show us some example documents, especially a small number that don't sort correctly in the pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one possible solution [here](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/mongodb-user/14442senqq/possible-bug-in-aggregation-framework-mongo-aggregation-framework-unable-to-sort-by-two-fields-on-big-collections). I have already tested it.

Answer (score 5):

Quoting the documentation:

> The `$sort` stage has the following prototype form:
>
> `{ $sort: { <field1>: <sort order>, <field2>: <sort order> ... } }`

So there are no limit on how many fields could be used on [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) stage.

---

However there are memory [*restrictions*](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#sort-and-memory-restrictions)
:

> The `$sort` stage has a limit of 100 megabytes of RAM. By default, if the stage exceeds this limit, $sort will produce an error. To allow for the handling of large datasets, set the [**`allowDiskUse`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) option to **true** to enable `$sort` operations to write to temporary files.

In `Pymongo` the syntax to use `allowDiskUse` option is:

```
collection.aggregate(
    [
        { '$sort': { <field1>: <sort order>, <field2>: <sort order> ... } }
    ],    
    allowDiskUse = True
)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no limit for sorting.[Mongo Documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/)

```
{ $sort: { <field1>: <sort order>, <field2>: <sort order> ... } }
```